# Localization not working in .NET6 Razor Pages project

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I was trying to get localization to work in my 'real' project, but was not able to do so. So I created a new stock .NET6 Razor Pages project to test localization in a fresh environment. However I am not quite able to do that there as well. At this point I have read about 6 articles, watched 2 tutorials and read the official documentation which says that it is up to date with .NET6, but I'm not sure about that (partly because the examples use old syntax, i.e. not things that came with .NET6). Every single one of those resources more or less did/said the same things, which is what I have right now, but it just doesn't work.

This is my Program.cs file:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); builder.Services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

var supportedCultures = new[] { "en" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

I have tested the "things I'll mention bellow" with `...AddRazorPages().AddData...` and (`AddMvc().AddData...` with `...AddRazorPages();`) as well. That's why one of those lines is commented.

The way I am testing the localization is just with an OnGet call on the Index page, and restarting the (local) server after every change just to not miss some dumb thing. On the OnGet, I just log the value to the console. But I'm always getting the key. Here is the IndexModel class:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> _localizer;

    public IndexModel(IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_localizer["Test"].Value);
    }
}
```

This is how my (relevant) folder structure looks like in the project's directory:
[image]

And finally the resx file:
[image]

Things I have tested are the .resx file names and the 2 possible locations. I am sure that both are correct, because when both files were active (neither had the .Dup (for duplicate) extension) at the end, I got an error from the compiler that multiple resources point to the same location or something like that.
The names I have tested are the following:

```
IndexModel.en.resx
Index.en.resx
IndexModel.cshtml.cs.en.resx
Index.cshtml.cs.en.resx
IndexModel.cs.en.resx
Index.cs.en.resx
```

Comment: So you mean you cannot get `This is a test!` in OnGet?If you try to add `?culture=en` in url,can you get the Value?Or you can try to test [Using one resource string for multiple classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary because I have this line in program.cs ```DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en")```. I have tested your theory anyway, but unfortunetely that didn't work, as expected. I have also tested it by using the one resource, but that didn't work either. I guess that my issue has something to do with .NET6 with razor pages. I don't have time to properly test other versions or MVC (on 6) though. So I have just created my own locallization tool. It ain't pretty but it gets the job done., for now at least. @YiyiYou

Comment: @TomekŚmigielski have you figured it out?

Comment: @Rico Like I said in the last part of my previous comment.

I have created my completely own localization (only translations actually) tool from scratch. It wasn't the best by far, but it got the job done.

Comment: @Rico

I remember I used a Dictionary<string, (enum, string)>

The dictionary key was just the language id (Ie. en, sp, ge etc.), the first value in the tuple was an enum which stored the string id's, and the second was the translation.

The dictionaries were in a standalone class, and I had a method which checked for the language, string id, and returned the translation. The language id was just a global value defined by a user.

Very simple, and suboptimal, but like I said, it got the job done. Since then I didn't need localization in any other of my projects. Good luck!